# asp.net controls values used on jquery ui dialog are empty in code behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am working on an asp.net application. I am using Jquery UI to add record to database. here is the markup.

```
 <div id="AddShippingPopup" class="popup" title="New Shipping Address">
        <p>Shipping Address</p>
         <table>
               <tr>

                    <td> Line 1:</td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtShippingLine1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                    <td>Line 2:</td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtShippingLine2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                    <td>City:</td>
                    <td> <asp:TextBox ID="txtShippingCity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                    <td>State:</td>
                    <td> <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlShipingState" runat="server" Width="200px" CssClass="required">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="">Please select</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="AK">Alaska</asp:ListItem>

                    </asp:DropDownList></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Zip:</td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtShippingZip" runat="server" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>  
                <tr>
                    <td>Preferred:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkPreferredShipAdd" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    </tr>  
         </table>
    </div>
```

and here is a button outside this div:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnAddShipping" runat="server" Text="Add Shipping" style = "display:none" OnClick = "btnAddShipping_Click" />
```

and Jquery dialog code:

```
     $("#AddShippingPopup").dialog({
                 autoOpen: false,
                 modal: true,
                 width: 500,
                 height: 370,
                 buttons: {
                     "Cancel": function () {
                         $(this).dialog("close");
                     },
                     "Save": function () {
                         $("[id*=btnAddShipping]").click();
                         $(this).dialog("close");
                     }
                 }
             });


function createShippingAddress() {
         $("#AddShippingPopup").dialog("widget").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
         $("#AddShippingPopup").dialog("open");
         return false;
     }
```

and here is link to initialize the dialog:

```
   <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAddNewShippingAddress" runat="server" Font-Size="Smaller" OnClientClick="createShippingAddress(); return false;">Add New</asp:LinkButton>
```

but values of text boxes and drop down are empty when Save button is clicked. and empty strings are saved in db. How to fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

The usual problem in this cases is that the javascript Dialog **is render their content out side of the asp.net form element**.

So force him to render inside the form by using the `appendTo` option. Here is an example from  [jQuery site](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-appendTo):

`$( ".selector" ).dialog({ appendTo: "#someElem" });`

and be sure that the element that you append to, is inside your asp.net form.

Your code will be as:

```
 $("#AddShippingPopup").dialog({
             appendTo: "#dialogAfterMe",
             autoOpen: false,
             modal: true,
             width: 500,
             height: 370,
             buttons: {
                 "Cancel": function () {
                     $(this).dialog("close");
                 },
                 "Save": function () {
                     $("[id*=btnAddShipping]").click();
                     $(this).dialog("close");
                 }
             }
         });
```

and place this div somewhere inside your form

```
<div id="dialogAfterMe"></div>
```